# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm running the unit tests in a react-native app I'm developing and three of them are failing with this message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined
```

The error does not seem to be caused by my code, but either by `react-test-renderer` (in two tests) and in `enzyme-adapter-react-16` (in one test).

This was an expo app and the unit tests were running. I then ejected. I replaced

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo"
},
```

with

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
},
```

and all my other tests are running. The three failing tests are the only ones that use `react-test-renderer` and `enzyme-adapter-react-16`.

I've tried (many times) removing `node_modules` and reinstalling. Here are the versions I'm using:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
  "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
  "enzyme": "^3.1.1",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.4",
  "eslint": "^4.9.0",
  "jest": "^21.2.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-native start",
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "test": "jest"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
},
"dependencies": {
  "assert": "^1.4.1",
  "react": "16.0.0",
  "react-native": "^0.50.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "yarn": "^1.3.2"
}*
```

Comment: I once had similar troubles because of the way npm took care of installing the dependencies and for reasons unknown to me, it worked using yarn.

Comment: @Gaellan Thanks. I'm already using yarn. You think I should try with `npm` instead? :-)

Comment: Can't (or at least it shouldn't) hurt to try :)

Comment: @Gaellan With npm I don't see to even be able to reach that point. All the tests are failing, and they are failin gearlier.

Comment: Did you have to react-native link at any point ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I only once had to work on an ejected app, and I remember that even though I had no additional dependencies installed I had to run   ̀react-native link` to make it all work. I might be grasping at straws here, just going from past bad experience :)

Comment: @Gaellan Thanks a lot! I'm not certain what `react-native link` does, but while trying to find out what it does I discovered I had lots of stuff installed on my global `node_modules`. I cleaned it up and then it worked! Probably some kind of interaction between my react/react-native/whatever modules with the global ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of others who have the same problem: it was fixed when I cleaned up my global `node_modules` and left `react`, `react-native`, and some other stuff only in the project's `node_modules`.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue and fixed it by installing react, react-dom and react-test-renderer of the same version.

Some background:

- I've got one project where mentioned packages are 16.2.0 (they were
  installed initially with that version) and everything works fine.
- On another project I had react and react-dom 15.4.2 and updating them
  to 16.2.0 by removing node_modules changing version in
  package.json    and installing all dependencies from scratch didn't
  help. I had to    roll react-test-renderer back to 15.4.2 and only
  then I managed to    get this issue resolved. I don't know whether
  this is project or    environment related issue but I never installed
  react or react-dom    globally.

So try making react-test-renderer the same version as your react and react-dom.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to update `react`, `react-dom` and `react-test-renderer` to `16.3.2`.

> It seems like one of them is 16 alpha which is not officially supported yet.

```
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2"
```

More details below:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2526#issuecomment-308081573

Comment: this one helped. Thank you!